# Return async in Web Api action

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have the following Web Api action

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get() {

  String clientId = "xyz";
  String clientSecret = "xyz";
  var config = new InstagramConfig("clientId", clientSecret);
  var query = new InstaSharp.Endpoints.Tags(config);

  var reply = query.Recent("car", null, null, 2);
  var images = reply.Result.Data;

  return await Ok(reply.Result.Data);

} // Get
```

A few notes:

1. query.Recent return type is await Task
2. reply.Result.Data type is List

When I compile the code I get an error:

Cannot await 'System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult>'

Does anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Async is useful when you do IO. Best position is when you query data from some source. So it would be query.recent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im pretty sure what you want is

```
var reply = await query.Recent("car", null, null, 2);
var images = reply.Result.Data;
return Ok(reply.Result.Data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var reply = await query.Recent("car", null, null, 2);
```